# how can i create a variable that sums specific rows based on a condition and use it in other formulas?

Tags: python, pandas, sum, transform

I am trying to group 'unique_id', and sum 'sum_ni' if 'twelve_wks_prior_TF' is True.

This is what I have but I cannot re-use this variable in other fields. After researching a bit I know I can't reuse it because the indexes aren't aligned.

How can I re-create the formula below and be able to re-use it in other calculations?

```
df_DTO2['twelve_wk_usage'] = df_DTO2[df_DTO2.twelve_wks_prior_TF == True
].groupby(['unique_id'])['sum_ni'].transform(sum))
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (untested) code. You have the right idea of filtering for `True`. It's redundant to specify `== True`. If you pass the boolean series, by *default*, it will filter for `True` values. Then, just take the max of each group from the newly created column:

```
 df_DTO2['twelve_wk_usage'] = df_DTO2[df_DTO2['twelve_wks_prior_TF']].groupby('unique_id')['sum_ni'].transform(sum)
 df_DTO2['twelve_wk_usage'] = df_DTO2.groupby('unique_id')['twelve_wk_usage'].transform(max)
 df_DTO2['current_wk_usage'] = df_DTO2['current_wk_usage'].astype(float)
 df_DTO2['twelve_wk_usage'] = df_DTO2['twelve_wk_usage'].astype(float)
 df_DTO2['12_wk_CGR'] = df_DTO2['current_wk_usage'] / df_DTO2['twelve_wk_usage']
 df_DTO2
```

Comment: i updated the code based on your suggestion above and it works alone, but when I try and use it in a new formula, for example: df_DTO['12_wk_CGR'] = (df_DTO['current_wk_usage'])/(df_DTO['twelve_wk_usage']). It returns null. The other variable ('current_wk_usage') is set up the same way twelve_wk_usage is. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @ChristaJacob please see my updated answer. Are you doing these calculations from one dataframe or are columns coming from two dataframes?

Comment: thanks for responding again. No, still not working and all results come up as null. Same dataframe. For some reason the boolean filter in the initial 'twelve_wk_usage' formula isn't permanently filtering out the Falses for that field. When I print the first 5 rows of the 'twelve_wk'_usage' variable before I enter the '12_wk_CGR' field, it includes Falses.